# How do we add a video to "Watch Later"?

Tags: youtube

Usually I'd like to chunk useful videos to "Watch Later". However YouTube just had a new interface change and I can't find this feature anymore. Does anyone know how to add a video to "Watch Later"?

Was this feature removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can still see it. Just hover over the video preview image and click the clock-like icon that appears.

[image]

To add the current playing video to the watch-it-later list, click on the clock-like icon from the player bar (see screenshot below).

[image]

There is also [this help page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1290556) describing the process.

Comment: Thanks it works, btw what if the video isn't at the side bar? I.e. The video that I want to "Watch Later" is the currently playing video?

Comment: @Pacerier see the second screenshot that I've added.